# pattern match and capturing in unix

Tags: linux, sed, awk, regular-expression, perl

I have a file like this:

```
A1-1915435_1_MIMAT0000069_MirBase_miR-16_microRNA_1_22-A1-1915435_1_ENSG00000206737_ENST00000384010_U1_snRNA_73_115
A1-2362643_1_MIMAT0000732_MirBase_miR-378_microRNA_1_21-A1-2362643_1_ENSG00000222328_ENST00000410396_U2_snRNA_168_211
```

I want an output in which I get micro RNA part and ENSG part tab separated. Some thing like this:

```
miR-16_microRNA ENSG00000206737
miR-378_microRNA    ENSG00000222328
```

I can write a perl script for it but I guess there must be command line solution for this using awk, sed perl etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -n 'y/_E/\t\n/;s/\n/E/;s/[^m]*//;s/\(A.\).*E/\1E/;P'
```

That works for me given your example...

```
miR-16  microRNA        ENSG00000206737
miR-378 microRNA        ENSG00000222328
```

If you want the first `\t`ab converted back to a `_` then you can add `s/\t/_/` before the `P` - but I think it looks nicer like this.

Another way could look like...

```
sed 's/RNA[^E]*_/RNA\t/;s/[^m]*//;s/_E.*//'
```

...or...

```
sed 's/[^mE]*\([mE][^mE_]*\)/\1/;s//\t\1/3;s/_E.*//'
```

...which both print what you show in your desired output like...

```
miR-16_microRNA ENSG00000206737
miR-378_microRNA        ENSG00000222328
```

. In any case you might have to use a literal character in place of the `\t` escape depending on your `sed` implementation.

Answer (score 6):

```
perl -pe 's!.*(miR-\d+_microRNA).*(ENSG\d+).*!$1\t$2!'
```

> explain a bit?

Sure, sorry:

- for each line (perl -p)
- substitute  regex by `$1 tab $2` where

  - `$1` and `$2` are numbered backreferences to capturing groups `(...)`. Nearly all modern regular expression engines support this.
- about the regular expression:

  - `.`  = any char except `\n`
  - `.*` = a sequence of chars (ignored in the substitution)
  - `\d` = digit (the same as `[0-9]`)
  - `\d+` = one or more `\d`

Please see any [reg expression tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) for a more detailed explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Using `sed`:

```
sed 's/^.*\(miR-[0-9]*_microRNA\).*\(ENSG[0-9]*\).*$/\1\t\2/' <infile
```

Answer (score 2):

Using [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) assuming the format is reliable :

```
$ awk -F'_' '{print $5"_"$6, $11}' file
miR-16_microRNA ENSG00000206737
miR-378_microRNA ENSG00000222328
```

Comment: why not `awk -F'_' '{print $5"_"$6, $11}'`